# StreamBuilder.periodic inside Drawer stops once drawer closed

Tags: flutter, dart

Following column is under `Drawer` of the `Scaffold`. When I open the drawer for the first time, widgets are created as intended. Once the drawer is closed, and reopened, `StreamBuilder` no longer functions. And all the widgets created before disappears.

```
Column(
  children: [
    StreamBuilder<List<BluetoothDevice>>(
      stream: Stream.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 2))
          .asyncMap(
              (_) => FlutterBluePlus.instance.connectedDevices),
      initialData: const [],
      builder: (context, snapshot) => Column(
        children: snapshot.data!.map((d) {
          String name =
              d.localName.isEmpty ? "Unknown" : d.localName;
          String btnText = "$name [${d.remoteId.toString()}]";

          return TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                d.disconnect();
              },
              child: Text(btnText));
        }).toList(),
      ),
    )
  ],
),
```

After hot restart, it starts working as intended again and creates the widgets. What could be the reason?

Comment: I've changed periodic interval to 100 milliseconds and it started behaving normal. I've no idea what's happening.